# Slow loading and responsiveness

Tags: loading, hybrid, responsiveness, stability

Our app loads extremely slowly, especially the pictures, and the developer has not been able to come up with a solution to this. The movements are slow and the buttons are slow in response (works on the 2nd or 3rd press).

The stability is terrible, for example the whole screen moves to the left by 2mm when you press a back button.

The app downloads information from the server every time it runs. We have tried changing the server, but this did not yield any results.

The current solution is to make the images smaller (compress them) to make the app run faster, but we are dubious if this will work.

Is there anybody who has had the same problems with their app?

I would be very grateful for any suggestions for how to fix this. We need it to be fast and responsive.

Answer (score 0):

These are very vague, general issues. You ideally need a developer to take a look at the whole problem.

Some things they may look into would be:

- Is data access asynchronous?
- Are there transitions running on the
  page?
- Are styles being added on hover or focus?

If the app is written badly, simply chucking more resources at it probably won't solve the problem.